How can a Date Range Picker in Flutter save the range on clicking 'Enter'?
I have added date range picker to my code. The user has to manually select save to choose the date range. I want the user to simply click the enter key and the range should be chosen. I cant seem to find any documentation on how to do this. I have inserted a screenshot of the UI of showDateRangePicker.
Screenshot of date time range picker
This is a snippet of my code
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

void _validateForm() {
  setState(() {
    _formKey.currentState?.validate();
  });
}

Future<void> _pickDateRange(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTimeRange? picked = await showDateRangePicker(
      context: context,
      firstDate: DateTime(2020),
      lastDate: DateTime(2100),
      initialDateRange: _dateRange,
    );

    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _dateRange = picked;
      });
      _validateForm();
    }
  }

I tried to use gesture detector but I'm not sure how to go about it.

What do you mean by clicking 'Enter'? When choosing a date range there is no keyboard where you can hit the Enter button, or do i miss something?

I mean the enter key on a laptop, when the user clicks this, I want it to save the date range. My web app requires inputting multiple date ranges so having this shortcut would increase the usability.
